# How to create a MySQL table or store the values in the MySQL table if values is of type python list

Tags: sql, mysql, data-modeling

I have the dataset where there the multiple columns where the value is of type python list.

How can I store that in the relational database table so that the retrieval also becomes efficient and correct.

Ex.

```
startup_name   sector
abc            [ML and AI, E-commerce]
xyz            [Manufacturing]
```

Comment: Shown data may be stored in the table which have 2 columns `startup_name` and `sector`. Shown data will be stored in 3 rows: ('abc', 'ML and AI'), ('abc', 'E-commerce'), ('xyz', 'Manufacturing').